# BrokeredMessage being disposed after await

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm trying to use a service bus Azure function, where I accept a BrokeredMessage, then perform http requests, and then afterward decide whether to complete, abandon, or dead letter the message. But I've been finding the BrokeredMessage is being disposed early if I await an http request. It's throwing `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'BrokeredMessage has been disposed.'` if I try to use it at all.

Example:

```
public static async void Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
            var httpClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://google.com")
            };
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            message.DeadLetter(); //Throws exception
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or missing something but I can't figure out how to make any actions I need to do with the message after the await work correctly.

Comment: Can you show us where your `Run` method is called? Your message may get disposed before. Your `Run` seems to not dispose your message.

Comment: I'm using an azure function with a service bus trigger, so this is the entry point (and the BrokeredMessage works as expected before the http call).

Comment: Is your method in the scope of your callback delegate from `SubscriptionClient.OnMessage` (I imagine you use this event)? Whenever the `SubscriptionClient.OnMessage` callback returns, the `BrokeredMessage` gets marked as disposed.

Comment: The azure function apparently handles the client for you, so the SubscriptionClient isn't really exposed. Basically what happens is what Mikhail described below. But you're still able to normally use methods like dead letter or abandon, just not in this case for some reason.

Comment: One thing that is not related to Functions - if you use async, don't return void. Return `Task`.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I actually also noticed that just now by tinkering around, and that actually fixes it! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped 

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `Complete()` explicitly. Azure Functions runtime will complete the message if the function finishes successfully or abandon if the function fails.

> The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode and calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails.

from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus)

Comment: I was just using that for an example, I've changed the example to be relevant. The problem is I may want to dead letter, abandon, look at delivery count, etc. based on the response from the http request, which I can't do.

Comment: @step5 I understand what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It looks like making my function return Task instead of void fixes it. Looks like the async wasn't working without that.

Comment: In my case i use a WorkerRole and changed to OnMessageAsync() that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the function needs to return `Task` instead of `void` for the async to work correctly. After making that change it awaits correctly.

Comment: In addition to returning a `Task` rather than `void`, you should also use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in a non-UI related code.